# Google cloud pub sub not receiving push notification to my endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I am using google cloud pub-sub push notifications to receive the latest emails.
But I am not receiving any notification at my endpoint.
What can be the issue, or how can I find out the issue?

Comment: When you say "to receive the latest emails," do you mean that you have set up [Gmail push notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push)?

Answer (score 0):

In the `Subscription` page you can find the details about the following details:

1. Unacked message count
2. Oldest unacked message age

From those two metrics you can try to debug whether the message actually received in the subscription or not.

Hope it helps.